# Ruby Array of Hash parsing

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, yaml, block

I have a yaml file in the format:

```
parameters:
  - param_name: age
    requires:
    - name
  - param_name: height
    requires:
    - name
```

Based on this format I would like to accept a hash of keys and values and determine if the combination of keys and values is valid. For example based on the above example if someone submitted a hash with the values:

```
{'age' => 15, 'height' => '6ft'}
```

it would be considered invalid since the parameter name is required. So a valid submission would look like

```
{'age' => 15, 'height' => '6ft', 'name' => 'Abe Lincoln'}.
```

Essentially what I want is this:

For each parameter object, if it has a requires array underneath it. Check all parameter param_names for elements in that array, if any are missing exit.

I have a very ugly double loop that checks for this but I want to tighten the code up. I think I can use blocks in order to validate the data I need. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
require 'yaml'
requirements = YAML.load_file('./require.yaml')
require_fields = Array.new

requirements['parameters'].each do |param|
  require_fields.concat(param['require']) if param.has_key? 'require'
end

require_fields.each do |requirement|
  found = false
  requirements['parameters'].each do |param|
    if param['param_name'] == requirement
      found = true
    end
  end
  abort "#{requirement} is a required field" unless found
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clean this up a lot if you make it more idiomatic Ruby:

```
require 'yaml'
requirements = YAML.load_file('./require.yaml')

require_fields = requirements['parameters'].select do |param|
  param.has_key?('require')
end.map do |param|
  param['require']
end

require_fields.each do |requirement|
  found = requirements['parameters'].any? do |param|
    param['param_name'] == requirement
  end

  abort "#{requirement} is a required field" unless found
end
```

You could also do this:

```
require_fields = requirements['parameters'].map do |param|
  param['require']
end.compact
```

Where that's probably good enough so long as your `require` is either something or `nil`.

You could also transform that input YAML into a simple hash structure of dependencies:

```
dependencies = requirements.map do ||
  [ param['param_name'], param['requires'] ]
end.to_h
```

Then you can test really easily:

```
dependencies.each do |name, requirements|
  found = requirements.find do |required_name|
    !dependencies[required_name]
  end

  abort "#{found} is a required field" unless found
end
```

This is a really rough adaptation of your code, but I hope it gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with subsequent checks, collecting errors and reporting all at once:

```
req = YAML.load 'parameters:
  - param_name: age
    requires:
    - name
  - param_name: height
    requires:
    - name'
input = {'age' => 15, 'height' => '6ft'}

req['parameters'].each_with_object([]) do |req, err|
  next unless input[req['param_name']] # nothing to check
  missed = req['requires'].reject { |param| input[param] }
  errors = missed.map do |param|
    [req['param_name'], param].join(' requires ')
  end
  err.concat(errors)
end
#⇒ ["age requires name", "height requires name"]
```

Or, chaining:

```
req['parameters'].each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |req, err|
  next unless input[req['param_name']] # nothing to check

  req['requires'].each do |param|
    err[param] << req['param_name'] unless input[param]
  end
end.map do |missing, required|
  "Missing #{missing} parameter, required for: [#{required.join(', ')}]"
end.join(',')
#⇒ "Missing name parameter, required for: [age, height]"
```